# values of a column to header

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following df:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'year' : ["2020", "2019", "2018"],
                   'Country': ["Germany","Austria","Spain"],
                   'Employees': [500000, 300000, 100000]
                 }, 
                  index = ['0', '1', '2'])
```

df
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZumR.png)

I would like to have:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLyv1.png)

I tried it with .melt and with .T but nothing worked.

Could you please help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df.pivot('Country', 'year', 'Employees')
```

Output:

```
year         2018      2019      2020
Country                              
Austria       NaN  300000.0       NaN
Germany       NaN       NaN  500000.0
Spain    100000.0       NaN       NaN
```

with `fillna`  and `reset_index`:

```
df.pivot('Country', 'year', 'Employees').fillna(0).reset_index()
```

Output

```
year  Country      2018      2019      2020
0     Austria       0.0  300000.0       0.0
1     Germany       0.0       0.0  500000.0
2       Spain  100000.0       0.0       0.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much!